# Why is glDrawElements giving me GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm only drawing 4 vertices. I'm trying to render a simple quad using `glDrawElements`, but nothing seems to work. I've written identical code in Java as well, and it works. This, however, does not.

Here's the drawing code:

```
glUseProgram(mProgram);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffers[0]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPosAttr);
glVertexAttribPointer(mPosAttr, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffers[1]);
if (er == 0){ er = glGetError(); std::cout<<gluErrorString(er)<<std::endl; }
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);


glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPosAttr);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glUseProgram(0);
```

I've left out useless things like `glUniform__` calls, I get the same result either way. Anyway, this prints "no error" the first time and then "out of memory" the second. That means it is most definitely caused by glDrawElements.

Why is this happening? What would fix it? Should I provide more code?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get that error earlier? `glError`s are accumulated and stored. Calling another GL function does not remove previous errors.

Comment: As I stated, I made absolutely **sure** it is coming from glDrawElements.

Comment: I do, at the end of the whole program.

Comment: Never mind, made a blunder in index buffer creation. Bound GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER but sent data to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. All I can say is... derp...

Comment: yes `glDrawElements` is throwing "Out of Memory" error when  index buffer has no data loaded (at least on my **nVidia**)

Answer (score 2):

In a comment the OP stated:

> As I stated, I made absolutely sure it is coming from glDrawElements.

However in the given source code

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffers[1]);
if (er == 0){ er = glGetError(); std::cout<<gluErrorString(er)<<std::endl; }
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
```

The error check is performed **before** glDrawElements. Also the error checking code is wrong. The correct method was:

```
while( (er = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR ){ std::cerr << gluErrorString(er) << std::endl; }
```

As already mentioned, error accumulate and must be queried to exhaustion in such a loop.

Why this error happens one can not tell without knowing more about the program: How is the context created, are extensions properly initialized, stuff like the. Ideally one had the full source code, or a minimal (not) working compilable example.

Comment: No, er is a private member of the class, and this code was run once every frame. The first frame gave no error as expected, and the second gave the error from glDrawElements, as expected.

Comment: @KyleEmmerich: Between those two frame iterations everything could happen.

Comment: Nothing else is happening, I made sure.